# How can I tell when the iOS simulator has booted to its home screen?

Tags: ios, ios-simulator

I use `open -n /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Applications/Simulator.app/ --args -CurrentDeviceUDID xxxxx` to start a simulator alongside any number of others, and I can poll `xcrun simctl list | grep xxxxx` to find out when it's started its boot process.

How can I determine that the simulator has finished its boot-up process and is idling at its home screen?

Currently I'm polling `~/Library/Logs/iOS Simulator/{version}/system.log` until it's quiet for a few seconds, but that's kinda lame.

Is there something nicer, like an `xcrun simctl getenv`?

Comment: What is the reason you specifically need to know that it is at the home screen (as opposed to just being ready to process a command like install or launch)?  Specifically, my point is that there ideally shouldn't be a need to know this information.

Comment: @Jeremy Huddleston Sequoia Presumably there's a reason the boot screen is still up: I'd prefer to test when the system is in the same state as when the user uses it.

Comment: There is no need.  The IPC blocks until checkin occurs.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could poll the com.apple.springboard.services mach service for checkin.  Eg:

```
~ $ simctl spawn booted launchctl print system | grep com.apple.springboard.services
         0x1c407    M   D   com.apple.springboard.services
...
~ $ simctl spawn booted launchctl print system | grep com.apple.springboard.services
         0x1c407    M   A   com.apple.springboard.services
```

edit:
With recent builds, you can also run `xcrun simctl bootstatus <UDID>` to monitor this progress.  That's likely a much more elegant solution than polling launchctl these days.

edit (again):
In addition to using 'xcrun simctl bootstatus ' to monitor the progress, you can use it to kick off the boot if it hasn't started already.  Check `xcrun simctl help bootstatus` for more info.

Comment: It's a couple of seconds earlier than the display, but it's pretty close. Thanks!

Comment: how do you poll booted state for specific device? like this? `~ $ simctl spawn <UUID> launchctl print system | grep com.apple.springboard.services`?

Comment: @the_prole yes, that's the way

Comment: Yes, it is indeed a couple of seconds earlier than the display. Is there another, better, solution?

Comment: Actually, as a matter of fact, now there is!  I'm going to update the answer =)