# How to boot iOS simulators asynchronously and wait on boot completion event with Bash script

Tags: ios, xcode, bash, ios-simulator

In my script, I want these iOS simulators to boot asynchronously to the main thread

```
boot B13D4F22-AA4E-4890-8C2B-3C5B7B6E3678 &
boot 5E2588E9-38B5-48AF-99C5-DEE8A1E6FDA0 &
boot 2C28BD02-18BE-4FC5-94DE-075880E70E60 &
boot 723705CD-B038-44E0-B42E-F1D29A28E85E &
```

and then I want to block until the polling for boot event on each sim returns true, or time-out, whichever happens first.

```
isSimBooted B13D4F22-AA4E-4890-8C2B-3C5B7B6E3678
isSimBooted 5E2588E9-38B5-48AF-99C5-DEE8A1E6FDA0
isSimBooted 2C28BD02-18BE-4FC5-94DE-075880E70E60
isSimBooted 723705CD-B038-44E0-B42E-F1D29A28E85E
```

Here is the entire script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

function isSimBooted()
{
    # Poll an iOS simulator for boot status in a time out loop.
    # https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37033405/
    # how-can-i-tell-when-the-ios-simulator-has-booted-to-its-home-screen

    UUID=${1}

    echo "isSimBooted"
    RESULT=$(xcrun simctl spawn ${UUID} launchctl print system | grep com.apple.springboard.services)
    echo "RESULT = "${RESULT}
    counter=$((0))
    while [ "$RESULT" = "" ]; do
        sleep 2
        ((counter++))
        RESULT=$(simctl spawn ${UUID} launchctl print system | grep com.apple.springboard.services)
        echo "waiting on boot event for device ${UUID}, RESULT = "${RESULT}
        if [ $counter -gt 90 ]; then
            echo "device ${UUID} took too long to boot"
            exit 1
        fi
    done
    echo "device ${UUID} booted successfully"
}

function boot()
{
  UUID=${1}
  xcrun simctl boot ${UUID}; open -a Simulator
}

echo "booting"

boot B13D4F22-AA4E-4890-8C2B-3C5B7B6E3678 &
boot 5E2588E9-38B5-48AF-99C5-DEE8A1E6FDA0 &
boot 2C28BD02-18BE-4FC5-94DE-075880E70E60 &
boot 723705CD-B038-44E0-B42E-F1D29A28E85E &

echo "waiting"

isSimBooted B13D4F22-AA4E-4890-8C2B-3C5B7B6E3678
isSimBooted 5E2588E9-38B5-48AF-99C5-DEE8A1E6FDA0
isSimBooted 2C28BD02-18BE-4FC5-94DE-075880E70E60
isSimBooted 723705CD-B038-44E0-B42E-F1D29A28E85E
```

The problem is that `RESULT` is always an empty string, such that the script gets caught in the boot poll loop until the timeout, even though the sims are clearly booted

```
while [ "$RESULT" = "" ]; do
    sleep 2
    ((counter++))
    RESULT=$(simctl spawn ${UUID} launchctl print system | grep com.apple.springboard.services)
    echo "waiting on boot event for device ${UUID}, RESULT = "${RESULT}
    if [ $counter -gt 90 ]; then
        echo "device ${UUID} took too long to boot"
        exit 1
    fi
done
```

And then If I run the script again **while the sims are booted**, `RESULT` is non empty and contains the string `com.apple.springboard.services` which indicates the sims are booted.

So I'm really not sure why If I run the script before the sims are booted, `RESULT` is an empty string, and if I run the script after the sims are booted `RESULT` is non empty.

Resources

[How to tell sim has booted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37033405/how-can-i-tell-when-the-ios-simulator-has-booted-to-its-home-screen)

Comment: Why do you want to wait for it to be booted? All the simctl commands (like install, launch, etc) should wait for their necessary dependencies to be ready. So if you attempt to install too early it should just block until the system is ready.

Comment: The app does bit get installed sometimes because the sims booy up to slowly. Sometimes the sims just freeze up.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you mostly had it.  Your script had an error inside the while loop.  You wrote:

```
RESULT=$(simctl spawn ${UUID} launchctl print system | grep com.apple.springboard.services)
```

But you should have put xcrun in front of simctl, like you did earlier in the script.

```
RESULT=$(xcrun simctl spawn ${UUID} launchctl print system | grep com.apple.springboard.services)
```

After that you may want to do some additional troubleshooting on your script.

I recommend you run your script at the command line in Terminal to troubleshoot.

Comment: Sweet I'll have to try this out